# How to hash two 32 bit integers into one 32 bit integers without collision?

Tags: hash

I am looking for a one-way hashing to combine two 32 bits integers into one 32 bits integer. Not sure if it's feasible to do it without collision.

Edit:
I think my integers are generally small. One of them rarely takes more than 14 bits, and the other one rarely takes more than 20 bits.

Edit 2: Thanks for the help in the comments. I think for cases like if the combination of two integers took more than 32 bits, I can do something differently to not hash it. With that, how should I hash my integers?

Thanks!

Comment: It's mathematically impossible to avoid collisions, by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  There are 2^32 32-bit integers, and 2^64 pairs.

Comment: Or think about it this way: consider the pairs of the form `(0,x)`, in which the first number is 0.  There are already the same number of such pairs as of available hash values, so they'll use up the entire space of hash values.  Then the hash of the pair `(1,0)` has to collide with one of them.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your setup? If you have a fixed collection of pairs that isn't "too big," you might be able to find a perfect hash function specifically for those pairs. But if you're trying to hash "general pairs," then as Nate Eldredge says there's no way to do this.

Comment: 14 + 20 is still more than 32, if you can restrict that just a little more and make it a guarantee then that's something we can work with